# If $\sin (\theta+\alpha)=a$ and $\sin(\theta+\beta)=b$, prove that, $\cos [2(\alpha-\beta)]-4ab\cos(\alpha-\beta)=1-2a^2-2b^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If $\sin (\theta+\alpha)=a$ and $\sin(\theta+\beta)=b$, prove that, $\cos [2(\alpha-\beta)]-4ab\cos(\alpha-\beta)=1-2a^2-2b^2$.

My Attempt:
.$$\sin (\theta+\alpha)=a$$
$$\sin \theta. \cos \alpha+\cos \theta.\sin \alpha=a$$
Multiplying both sides by $2$
$$2\sin \theta.\cos \alpha + 2\cos \theta.\sin \alpha=2a$$
Squaring both sides,
$$4\sin^2 \theta.\cos^2 \alpha + 6\sin^2 \theta. \cos^2 \alpha + 4\cos^2 \theta.\sin^2 \alpha=4a^2$$.

How should I do further?

Comment: Do you see that you can assume without loss of generality that $\theta=0$? Or perhaps (still wlog) assume $\theta=\pi/2$ instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\cos(\alpha-\beta)=\cos\{\theta+\alpha-(\theta+\beta)\}$$

$$=\cos(\theta+\beta)\cos(\theta+\alpha)+\sin(\theta+\beta)\sin(\theta+\alpha)$$

$$\implies\cos(\alpha-\beta)=\cos(\theta+\beta)\cos(\theta+\alpha)+ab$$

$$\implies\{\cos(\alpha-\beta)-ab\}^2=\cos^2(\theta+\beta)\cos^2(\theta+\alpha)$$

Now $\cos^2(\theta+\beta)=1-b^2, \cos^2(\theta+\alpha)=?$

Finally, $\cos2A=2\cos^2A-1$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: could you please elaborate about your 4th step?

Comment: @Ramanujan, r u talking abt the squaring?

Comment: No. How did you get $ab $?

Comment: @Ramanujan, What are the values of $\sin(\theta-\beta),\sin(\theta-\alpha)?$

Comment: I don't know! We only have the values of $\sin (\theta+\alpha)$ and $\sin (\theta+\beta)$, don't we?

Comment: @Ramanujan, Sorry for the typo & confusion.

Comment: it's OK. And thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0):

Consider a circle with radius $\frac{1}{2}$ and a triangle $ABC$ inscribed in the circle with $\angle A = 180^\circ - (\alpha+\theta), \angle B = \theta + \beta$. Then $\angle C = \alpha - \beta$. With the usual notations, we have $a = \sin(\theta+\alpha), b = \sin(\theta+\beta), c= \sin(\alpha - \beta)$. Applying the Cosine rule, $
c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos C $ gives the desired result.

Comment: why is radius to be considered as $\dfrac {1}{2}$?

Comment: We need to use the formula $\frac{a}{\sin A} = 2R$, when $R = \frac{1}{2}$, we get $a = \sin A$ etc

Comment: Is it allowed directly to construct a circle with $R=\dfrac {1}{2}$.? And, why should the angles be as $\angle A=180-(\alpha+\theta)$, $\angle B=\theta+\beta$ and $\angle C=\alpha-\beta$? why in this order only?

Comment: @LeonhardEuler We need to do this so that we can use the Sine formula in the triangle. When the angles are as given, the opposite sides have length as required.

Answer (score 0):

Set $\alpha-\beta=\gamma$, $\varphi=\theta+\alpha$, $\psi=\theta+\beta$; then $\gamma=(\theta+\alpha)-(\theta+\beta)=\varphi-\psi$, so
$$
\cos\gamma=
\cos\varphi\cos\psi+
\sin\varphi\sin\psi=
ab+\cos\varphi\cos\psi
$$
Also
$$
\cos2\gamma=2\cos^2\gamma-1=
2(a^2b^2+2ab\cos\varphi\cos\psi+\cos^2\varphi\cos^2\psi)-1
$$
so that
$$
\cos2\gamma-4ab\cos\gamma=
-2a^2b^2+2\cos^2\varphi\cos^2\psi-1
$$
Now $\cos^2\varphi=1-a^2$ and $\cos^2\psi=1-b^2$.